# Can I save a PGM file (portable gray map) somehow with Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Export only seems to export .png files, regardless what I put in the filename.
If not, what else could I use to create such a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create PGM files with GIMP (available from the Software Centre). This is made going to *File* -> *Export As...* and then selecting *PGM* in the *All export images* drop down list.

Inkscape should be able to import files in PGM format but it is not able to save them.